# Content gets cut off

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am developing a design that is supposed to become responsive in the end. It also is supposed to look clean and simple. But while developing, I realized something: When I open the page on my Mac - Chrome - it displays fine. But upon resizing it, or opening the same page on a smaller display device, the bottom is cut off...

I have used the web inspector, changed everything that I saw to something else but couldn'T figure out where the problem is. So I really need help here, as I got lost.

The basic idea:
http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/

The demo site:
http://dev.dragonsinn.tk

The code is hosted on a Gitlab repo on my server; here:
http://git.ingwie.me/ingwie/bird3/blob/master/cdn/themes/dragonsinn/css/main.ws.php

The problem is, that in order to simplify my CSS coding, I used my self-made CSS framework, WingStyle ( http://github.com/IngwiePhoenix/WingStyle ). It is meant to look like CSS, but offer better options for cross-browser compatiblity. So don'T get scared of the not-quite-CSS syntax :)

To reproduce the problem:
Open the site mentioned above, and resize your window. Then, open the right panel by hitting the pac-man icon (top right) and try to scroll down. You **should not** be able to see the version information. Resize the window, and at the bottom of the right panel, you may see a version string (`BIRD@3.0.0-dev...`).

How can I it possible, that it actually does scroll?

Comment: You could try using this library instead... http://scotch.io/bar-talk/scotchpanels-js-dead-simple-off-canvas-jquery-plugin

Comment: @bobbyg603: Does this allow me to have multiple panels (top, left, right, maybe bottom) at once?

Comment: Not entirely sure... sorry!

Comment: Author of that plugin here - it does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without studying your code to deeply I'd suggest you change your panel css as follows:

```
.panel-side { 
    width: 240px; 
    /* height: 100%; replaced with bottom: 0*/ 
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1000; 
    overflow-y: auto; 
}
```

This will give you a 100% percent height container and all overflowing content will be scrollable.

Comment: This aproach seems to work for now. I don't mind the scrolling myself, but Ill have to see how other browsers will render it. Thanks for this one!